# new position of creature without using a library

Tags: python, 2d, game-physics

Given the position of the creature, and the position of it's target, I'm trying to calculate the path to follow, limited by movement and rotation speed.

The creature has a look-orientation, and can only move forward along that orientation. It can not sidestep.

I am able to calculate the angle of difference between the creature's look-orientation and the target's position with the following code

```
def calculateAngleDifference(self):
    deltaX = self.position_x - self.target[0]
    deltaY = self.position_y - self.target[1]
    try:
        #atan is inverse tan
        delta = degrees(atan(deltaY / deltaX)) - self.orientation
    except:
        delta = degrees(atan(deltaY / 1)) - self.orientation
    return delta//1
```

this gives me a correct result, and stops when the creature is looking directly to the target.

However, I would like to move it during the same time, and thus the creature should walk a curve. It is impossible to have a target that is more than 45° different.

for the position calculation I use

```
def pointOnCircle(origin,  distance=50, degree = 45, method=cos):
    return origin + distance * method(radians(degree))

newX = pointOnCircle(self.position_x,  distance=1, degree = 1, method=cos)
newY = pointOnCircle(self.position_y,  distance=1, degree = 1, method=sin)
# input()
self.position_x = newX
self.position_y = newY
```

However, this never gets me to the target.

Comment: What is the creature? What is the position? What is the context? Are you making a game?

Comment: Not sure why the context would be relevant, but even so: I'm making a creature simulation evolutionary system. The creature is just that. A creature. The target in this case is a piece of food, and as such is stationary. Could have been anything though. Position is X,Y coordinates relative to bottom left due to piglet Coord system

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- from only reading your question, I don't know what you're doing at all. Now I can guess that you're making a 2D movement grid where one unit can see 45* and is going to automatically move towards a stationary object. However, your examples are not minimal, complete, or verifiable; I can't run your code and confirm that there is an incorrect result.